# How to feed IBM MQ logs into Splunk?

Tags: logging, java, splunk, ibm-mq

Our Java-program talks to IBM MQ using IBM-provided `com.ibm.mq.allclient` JAR. As [documented by IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=jms-logging-mq-classes), log-messages generated from within the JAR are written out into `mqjms.log` in the current directory.

The above link explains, how the location -- and/or the filename -- can be changed, but that's all the flexibility there is documented...

Our own code uses log4j with appenders configured for both local files and for the corporate Splunk -- using Splunk's own JARs.

Is it possible to configure IBM MQ client JAR to feed log-entries directly into Splunk as well? [Splunk document, how to feed their server from several Java logging frameworks](https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/devtools/java/logging-java/) -- is IBM MQ using any of them? Can it be made to?

Update: I'd rather not feed Splunk by way of *printing* -- be it into a file watched by Splunk Forwarding Agent -- or other means. Because the printed log-entry loses some information. And because multi-line entries (such as those with Java-exceptions) will generate a logging event *for each line*.

Comment: Could you install the splunk client forwarder to just tail that file locally?

Comment: Besides pointing to a specific file the only other option you have is to tm point to System.err or System.out, could you use something like [this](https://edivad.wordpress.com/2007/02/26/systemout-and-systemerr-over-log4j/amp/) to have System.err go to log4j which is then configured to send to splunk?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions -- I updated the question with the explanation, why I'd rather not go through text-file.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @MikhailT. My suggestion was not the go through a file.   My suggestion was to configure MQ to send messages to System.err or System.out and then per the link I provided redirect System.err or System.out to log4j configured like you mentioned with appenders configured for Splunk.  This would not involve a text file.